# Python - Developing Web Application

Tags: python

I am trying to self-learn developing Web applications using Python as backend. Since I am from C++ background I find difficulty in building web pages (design / implementation) and backend code associated to it – creation of CSS, HTML code, including Images, tables etc.  I read about http://webpy.org/ framework but have not yet used it. In actual I am a bit confused how to develop a great UI page using Python – something like page having multiple tabs, color scheme, drop box, list, graphs and other UI component / widgets - and ofcouse backend code associated to it.

Can anyone please let me know what path we should take so that the same can be made easy? I read about JQuery and believe that in computing world there are a lot of tools like that available but which combinations stands the best and .. easy to work with.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really on topic for Stack Overflow - but let me mention that all the great UI stuff you talk about, like multiple tabs, color scheme, drop box, list, graphs, etc. has _nothing_ to do with what you write in Python. All that is done in HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: Developing Web App using Python - the UI interface / component is very important. So for writing Python web apps we need to know these also? In other words knowing Python we cannot create good web pages - for that we need to learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: @Prakash: Logic first, then presentation. Of course you can build a web app without JS and I'd recommend that every website should also work for users with Javascript enabled. That said, you need to know some HTML and CSS, but those aren't programming languages, but basically a structured way to describe your application's output.

Comment: @Prakash Correct, you will need to know some basic HTML and CSS at least. A good place to start is [w3schools](http://w3schools.com), which has free tutorials on HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

First, check [w3schools.com][1] out,

Read on about 1)HTML, 2) CSS, 3) JavaScript 4) PHP

If you really want to build web apps fast, i'd recommend you to choose php over python, because php especially designed to build dynamic web apps.

Comment: I understand that whether I use PHP or Python or any backend platform - I need to learn and understand HTML / CSS / JavaScript

Comment: Python vs. PHP is a matter of personal preference, please try and stick to facts in your answers.

Comment: @agf, read on: http://klau.si/sites/klausi.fsinf.at/files/php-vs-python-vs-ruby.pdf

Comment: "Python was designed as a full-featured general purpose lang from the begining AND WAS NOT specialized to be used as as a web scripting language LIKE PHP"

Comment: @metal_fan Yes, that's what PHP was designed for. But that doesn't mean it's _better_ or _faster_ at it. Many, many people would argue that Python is far better and faster for building an app that does anything useful.

Comment: @agf by the way, PHP 5.4 is much faster than < PHP 5.3.x

Comment: @afg http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonVsPhp

Comment: @metal_fan I've extensively used both languages for web development. By "faster" I didn't mean how long it takes a page to load, but how long it takes to create a useful application from scratch. Yes, in Python you use a framework like Django, and in PHP you don't, but you still have something real and useful faster. That page described the choices you make when you decide between Python and PHP, it doesn't make any judgement between which is better for developing web applications.

Comment: @agf How to create a useful web app from scratch - Well, this time it doesn't matter which lang is being used to do this. it totaly depends on skills of developer ie. For example if you are developed 20-30 different cms products you can create almost the same using another langs, like Ruby, Perl even ASP.NET(C#). If we develop any custom product we are focusing on it's structure firstly (MVC), but not language syntax we use. Django is good enough to build web apps fast because it has all common feautures that simplifies page handling, mean - session, validator and so on. That's true.

Comment: But Zend Framework allows us to build a very robust and clean web-apps very fast. We only create instances of classes that already was written.

Comment: You're proving my point. Which is better is a matter of opinion.

Comment: http://w3fools.com It's best not to recommend an unreliable resource

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee not recommended for professionals. But not for beginners. It's great enuf to very beginners, because it has simply example codes for html & css & js for easy understanding.

Comment: @metal_fan Take a look at the link I posted. The last thing you want to do is teach beginners bad habits and wrong practices from the start... There are much better resources out there (e.g. MDN Docs or HtmlDog).

Comment: @metal_fan: check http://w3fools.com/ Saying that w3schools is easy for beginners may be true, but is also poison for them. HtmlDog is *very* complete and is easy as well.

Also, saying that php is "better" than Python is just stupid. Not starting a flame war, I ditto the comments from the others above.

Comment: @emyller I didn't say `Python` is better than `PHP` (read the text!). I said PHP is more suited for web that python because PHP was designed for web from the ground. Also, I'm well aware of w3fools, but there's nothing wrong with PHP section on the site. w3schols contains incorrect information on HTML lessons, but not on PHP. You can check that. W3school (despite what w3fools say) has a decent PHP tutorial for "very" beginners. That's the point.

Answer (score 10):

You can't run python in the browser.  So, for web development it's used exclusively on the server side.  And really it's whole purpose is to enforce your business logic and generate the markup for your site.  Then the client side technologies (HTML5+Browser, Javascript and CSS) take over.

On the server-side, Django is really popular right now.  It is quite robust and has a very active community behind it.  I would recommend that you look at the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).  For the client side, jQuery is very popular and has a HUGE community behind it.  There are many, many tutorials out there - just google "jQuery tutorial".

If you are not very good with CSS (and it sounds like you might not be), then I would personally recommend one of the grid-based CSS frameworks.  They make it a lot easier to get a professional looking site.  And with the responsive frameworks, then you have the added benefit of being quasi-mobile enabled.  There are a bunch of them.  Including one of the originals [Grid 960](http://960.gs/), but again there are many.  Here's a pretty good [blog post](http://creativeproject.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/16-best-css-frameworks-for-all-projects-types/) on 16 of them.

As for controls/widgets, there are several to choose from.  [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) is very good and popular.  While not as popular, [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) is still a good option to check out.  [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) is good, but not free.  And the list goes on...  YUI, etc.  You will probably just want to pick one with a good community behind it and learn it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this contributes to the discussion as it helped me a bit in making Python great for the web.

Metalfan, I saw you asking on the chat:

> Are there any libraries which makes Python work like PHP. I mean embed
>   into HTML something like

You're asking about a templating library to build html, css, javascript, sql or anything else. I've searched for a tool to do that, and found [Cog](http://www.python.org/about/success/cog/), [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) and most of what else Google throws at you. I was inspired by what I was in Django, which gives the template processing access to objects and basically the whole language, instead of only doing macro-expansion.
[Web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) has a module that does just that, and I've found it very easy to modify or use stand-alone. I can't remember if I've made any modifications to the original, [so I've uploaded the version](http://pastie.org/4775988) I'm using, so it should work out of the box.

To generate code from a template, you include the **template** module, and call the render function with a template (string) and a context (dict containing local environment). Like this:

```
from template import render
import urllib2

environment = dict(
    elements=[1, 2, 3],
    username="mortn",
    session_id="xyz",
    lam=lambda x=0: urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").read(),
    f=f,
    )

print render(content=html_template, context=environment)
```

The template would then look like this:

```
<html>
 <h1>Hello {{= username }}</h1><br/>
 {{ if session_id=="xyz": }}
 {{   # indentation doesn't matter.. }}
   this isn't printed unless if-statement matches
 {{ else: }}
   instead this would be shown
 {{ pass  # each if/for/while statements (that would 
 {{       # "indent your code"), must end with pass }}
 {{ for e in elements: }}   - {{=e}}
 {{ pass }}
 {{ # demo of looping }}
 {{ if 1: }} 
 {{ for i in xrange(10): }}<br/>{{ pass }}
 {{ pass }}
 {{ # imported function }}
 100 chars of google html get:
 {{ =lam()[:100] }}
 {{ # you can access the whole language with this }}
 {{ =f()}}
```

.... and it gives THIS output:

```
<html>
 <h1>Hello mortn</h1><br/>
   this isn't printed unless if-statement matches
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
   <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
100 chars of google html get:
&lt;!doctype html&gt;&lt;html itemscope=&quot;itemscope&quot;itemtype=&quot;http://schema.org/WebPage&quot;&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta itemprop
you can do whatever
```

It messes a bit with the white spacing as you'll see, I've shortened the output down as each {{ block generates a newline. It can be edited in the template.py module as it has VERY readable code that adheres to PEP8.

**TL;DR:
Here's the link for the sample code in a single file: 
http://pastie.org/4776120
and the template.py module: http://pastie.org/4775988**